# Object output returning NAN

Tags: javascript, object

This is my code

```
const products = 
      [ 
          {

    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto",
    "coefficient":2,
    "price": () => 2000 * this.coefficient
  },
  {

    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla",
    "coefficient":3, 
    "price": () => 2000 * this.coefficient
  },
]
```

I want to return the price depends on the coefficient, but when i excute

```
products[0].price() // return NaN
```

how can i fix that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This is due to the way that arrow functions handle the `this` scope. In this case, replacing the arrow function (`() => this.something`) with a traditional JS function (`function() { return this.something; }`) will solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

The `this` in an arrow function refers to the class scope, that is an empty object; in that case, yo refer to the the object scope you must use the full function syntax.

Try this:

```
products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title:
      "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    body:
      "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto",
    coefficient: 2,
    price: function() {
      return 2000 * this.coefficient;
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "qui est esse",
    body:
      "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla",
    coff: 3,
    price: function() {
      return 2000 * this.coefficient;
    }
  }
];

console.log(products[0].price()) // 4000
console.log(products[1].price()) // 6000
```

Comment: Maybe a little explanation for OP would be helpful to add.

Comment: Explanation: as you can see, the "this" in an arrow function referes to the class scope, that is an empty object in that case, To refer to the the object scope you must use the full function syntax.

Answer (score 4):

For the arrow functions, value of `this` is not based on the object reference using which the function was executed. Rather it uses the `this` reference from the closure where it was declared. Check [the documentation here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this). In your scenario `this.coefficient` would be undefined, which when multiplied with `2000` results in `NaN`.

You can change the arrow functions to proper functions if you need `this` to refer to the object reference on which `price` function was called. Changed code should be something like this:

```
products = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto",
    "coefficient":2,
    "price": function() { return 2000 * this.coefficient; }
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
                const products =
                [
                    {

                        "id": 1,
                        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
                        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto",
                        "coefficient": 2,
                        price() {
                            return 2000 * this.coefficient
                        }
                    },
                    {

                        "id": 2,
                        "title": "qui est esse",
                        "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla",
                        "coefficient": 3,
                        price() {
                            return 2000 * this.coefficient
                        }

                    },
                ]
```

Comment: Nice way to represent the function.

Comment: Yes it's also a way